# Automatic Picture at the Finish Line

Tags: equipment-recommendation, sports, triggers, triggertrap

I would like to take pictures of my cross country team as they cross the finish line (with the clock in the picture).

I am thinking that I will need a laser beam to be broken as they cross the line that will then trigger the camera which will be mounted in a different location.

What do I need to consider in both technique and equipment in order to pull this off?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you need a laser trigger on the finish line.
Check out something like the [Cactus lv5](https://www.cactus-image.com/lv5.html)

As for other equipment you'll need a tripod and possibly one or two flash units depending on your lighting situation.
You'll want to use completely manual settings to keep all photos exactly equal.
Most importantly you'll want to keep a reasonably high shutter speed to prevent any movement in the photo.

Comment: Just an FYI. An acquaintance showed me one of these. It looks interesting but I've not personally tried it yet.    https://www.miops.com/miops-smart/  .  It runs about $200.

Comment: @user10216038 I also came across that device while searching but didn't add it to my answer because it seems to require a third party laser (handheld pointer shown in example). and might not even be able to be set up of camera.